# What is known about the possibility of making a program to validate another program for correctness?

Tags: correctness-proof, formal-methods, software-verification, program-correctness

I'm having a question inspired by exercise 14 from section 1.2.1 of Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming. It's phrased in the following way:

> (R. W. Floyd) Prepare a computer program that accepts, as input, programs in some programming language together with optional assertions, and that attempts to fill in the remaining assertions necessary to make a proof that a computer program is valid.

Knuth directs to see the papers by R. W. Floyd and J. C. King in IFIP Congress proceedings, 1971. However, this document turned out to be very hard to find in the Internet, whilst being necessary to understand the problem better.

I do want to know whether this problem is still unsolved as it was when Knuth last updated that book, and, whether it is solved or not, I want to shed some more light for myself into this problem by reviewing additional related sources connected to it which you know and can share, as the Internet that I know turned out to be a scarce place for such information.

Comment: One can iterate through all possible "proof" objects and check each one if they are correct or not. This is not practical, but in terms of theory it is capable of proving *correct programs* (whilst it will get stuck in an infinite loop for incorrect programs)

Comment: If you are interested in automated proving, then you might want to read [this collection of books](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

Comment: [Questions tagged with "software verification"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-verification), [questions tagged with "automated-theorem-proving"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automated-theorem-proving)